# How to access Excel PROTECTED spreadsheet in SharePoint Web Access Web Part in SharePoint2013?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have excel file which is protected by password. I need to access Sheet 1 on SharePoint Web Part Page on Dashboard. While I add protected I can not able to Excel Sheet is corrupted as 
per below image.!

[image]

While I add simple Excel Spreadsheet, it works properly. Is there any alternate solution to display excel spreadsheet on Web Page using Excel Services.

Answer (score 1):

according to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6, protected workbooks/sheets cannot be viewed in SP2013.

"Worksheet protection or workbook protection:

Workbooks that are protected (encrypted with password protection) cannot be viewed in a browser window.

Protected worksheets (not entire workbooks) can be viewed in a browser window in Excel Online.

In an on-premises environment where you're using Excel Services or Excel Web App, protected worksheets cannot be viewed in a browser window.

To remove protection, open the workbook in the Excel."